# Why are my eclipse dp dimensions for the android graphical layout editor not accurate?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

While trying to make a layout for my app, I noticed that while using the QVGA skin(240 by 320) I noticed a button 240dp by 160 dp does not fill half of the screen vertically, nor the entire screen horizontally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think that 1dp equals 1px, which is not *(always)* correct.

It depends on the screen density *(thats how many pixels are displayed per inch)* how many pixels equal 1dp. The 1 to 1 conversion only applies at 160 dpi *(mdpi in android terms)*. If you have a QVGA display created in the emulator/eclipse, chances are that it's density is 120 aka ldpi *(by default)*, so you get other dimensions. 1dp is smaller than 1px in this case, resulting in a smaller view.

See the [dp description in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) for more information.